# I have created a new custom module and it is working fine from back end, but in front data is not displaying

Tags: module, magento-1, custom

```
<?php
    $model = Mage::getModel('custom_homebanner/request')->getCollection()
?>
<div class="owl-carousel"  id="owl-demo-intro" >
    <div class="item">
        <h2 class="all_caps color_white"><?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text ?></h2>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1 class="color_white all_caps"><?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text1 ?></h1>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2 class="color_white all_caps"><?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text2 ?></h2>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
<?php echo $banner->getCustomHomebannerText(); ?>
```

Instead of

```
<?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text ?>
```

If still not works then print your collection and check if the values are correctly showing or not.

Comment: This code is not working.

Comment: Can you check the model name? Is it correct or recheck the model?

Comment: Model name is: custom_homebanner

Comment: Try this code Mage::getModel('custom/homebanner')->getCollection();

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing data wrong way. Please follow below way:

```
  $model = Mage::getModel('custom_homebanner/request')->getCollection();
  foreach($model as $data){
   echo $data->getCustomHomebannerText();
  }
```

Comment: Try to understand my question and the code which I wrote.

Comment: have you getting collection ?

Comment: Not yet, but I tried the above code also.

Comment: <?php
        $model = Mage::getModel('custom_homebanner/request')->getCollection();
          foreach($model as $data){
        echo $data->getCustomHomebannerText();
  }

Comment: <div class="owl-carousel"  id="owl-demo-intro" >
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="all_caps color_white"><?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1 class="color_white all_caps"><?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text1 ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="color_white all_caps"><?php echo $banner->custom_homebanner_text2 ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: The above mentioned code which I'm using php & html to get the data from the back end.

Comment: Can you update how the $banner object defined?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using collection and want to loop and print the data then use for loop to iterate over it.

```
<?php $model = Mage::getModel('custom_homebanner/request')->getCollection(); ?>
<div>
    <?php foreach($model as $banner): ?>
    <div>
       <h2 class="all_caps color_white"><?php echo $banner->getCustomHomebannerText() ?></h2>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1 class="color_white all_caps"><?php echo $banner->getCustomHomebannerText1() ?></h1>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2 class="color_white all_caps"><?php echo $banner->getCustomHomebannerText2() ?></h2>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

If you want the first Item from your collection you should use `getFirstItem()` method

```
<?php $model = Mage::getModel('custom_homebanner/request')->getCollection()->getFirstItem(); ?>
<div>
    <div>
       <h2 class="all_caps color_white"><?php echo $model->getCustomHomebannerText() ?></h2>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have Id of the Item you want you can use `load()` method

```
<?php $model = Mage::getModel('custom_homebanner/request')->load(1); ?>
<div>
    <div>
       <h2 class="all_caps color_white"><?php echo $model->getCustomHomebannerText() ?></h2>
        <!-- <figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure> -->
    </div>
</div>
```